# Passing text into a label on tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, label

I have a 2 files: main.py and gui.py. Main.py - kinda back end, where all calculations are happening.
gui.py is a front side. I am having problem with passing the text from main.py to the label in gui.py.

```
predicted = loaded_model.predict(X_new_tfidf)
print(category_list[predicted[0]])
gui.lblClassify.set(category_list[predicted[0]])
```

The `print(category_list[predicted[0]])` is giving a output (text) that i have to pass to the label in gui.

Label in *gui.py* looks like the following:

```
lblClassify = tk.Label(frame, textvariable = buttonText)
lblClassify.place(relx=0.69, rely=0.6, relheight=0.1, relwidth=0.3)
lblClassify.pack()
```

Comment: You should update the variable `buttonText` instead.

Comment: Can you clarify? @acw1668

Comment: I dont know about your architecture, if you use class you need to put self. in front of the var like self.lblClassify. Why do you place and pack the Label? I think you have some more problems than this. Also it would be better to set the StringVar() instead of the Label. The Label you can configure the StringVar() can be set.

Comment: As your code has associated the tkinter variable `buttonText` to `textvariable` option when creating the label, you should know that updating `buttonText` will update the text of the label as well, unless `buttonText` is not a tkinter variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method out:
    `lblClassify = tk.Label(frame, text = "Your text goes here")`

if you want to change text after creation of Label, this should do the trick:
    `lblClassify.config(text="Updated value")`